# Setting up a client to server (and database) connection and updating client html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mariadb

I'm setting up a web-server that the client would communicate with to get data from a database.

I am have both my server and database set up on localhost (1234 and 3306) and I want my client to receive the data and have a certain DOM element be updated

I understand this might be an XY problem, so I'll give appropriate context. This is the scenario I'm trying to build:
User clicks on element, element pops in front of user (iframe), said iframe contains basic html for an about page, its content is updated correspondingly to the element clicked. Suppose user clicked element cat, element cat in database is id=3 in its table, id=3 will be enough to access the cat txt and jpg contained in its directory then these will show on the iframe.

The content updating is what I'm asking about here and how to set this up correctly, I have no restrictions to what I can do, but I would prefer doing it in javascript (because I already understand it)

I have looked up a bunch on mariadb and sqlite and have both setup and been trying to make both do what I want, to no avail.

Code giving here is just to show what I have tried, I don't know if this is the correct solution for my problem:

```
this.server.on("request", (request, response) => {
                if (request.url == "/build/app/description.html"){
                    mariadb.createConnection({host: '127.0.0.1', user: 'root', password: 'woopdidoo', database: 'baseddata', port: '3306', multipleStatements: true})
                        .then(conn => {
                            conn.query('SELECT type FROM expertise; SELECT type FROM expertise; SELECT type FROM expertise;')
                            .then (rows => {
                                for (var i = 0; i < (rows.length); i++){
                                    console.log(rows[i]);
                                }
                                response.write('some html');
                                response.end();
                                conn.end();
                            })
                            .catch (err => {
                                console.log('Request error');
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            //handle error
                            console.log('Connection error');
                        });
                }else{
                return console.debug(`Received request ${request.method} ${request.url}`);
                }
            });
```

I have tried using the response.write method which works, but :
1- It overwrites whatever HTML I have (understandable)
2- If I make the same request again, it will fail and my server will crash (end before write error)

Is my approach coherent to what I'm trying to do? If not, how would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STEP1: Create Endpoint

Serverside you have to do two things.
- Create new Route
- Edit the HTML-File which you will serve

You can do a new GET-Route.

```
router.get('expertise/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  let id = req.params.id;
});
```

With: http://127.0.0.1/expertise/2 you get the 2 as id.

STEP2:
Add javascript to the html-file, which you serve. You can add the javascript inside the html-file or as an external file, where you can link to it.

Comment: I have not tried this yet but the method used seems to be exactly what I want to do. Thank you for bringing this up. I have a question though, what does creating a new route do? In this case, won't (http)server.on('request') and getting the request url (this can be done dynamically like your example) do the same thing?

Comment: sorry i dont understand the question completly, but i think you seems to have a problem with routing.
have a look at express. its a real good framework for node.js.
https://expressjs.com/de/
Routing is that easy.

You can generate the project with express generator and add some new routes. I like express, it is also really nice for bigger projects.

I will give it a chance, if you have any questions, dont hesitate to ask. 
If you use help with coding, or starting project, i ca upload you a projekt to git if you want. But i think, aso more you do by yourself, as better it is.

Answer (score 0):

this is my first post and i hope it will help you.

So, your problem is just to update the modalview, if the user clicks on a preview?
There are multiple approaches i think.

AJAX;
I would prefer to add an click eventhandler on the DOM, which will get clicked.
After a click fired the event, you can do an ajax request to the server, which will answer. You can do a get request with tha parameter id, so the server knows, which element he has to search.

A simple way, quick, dirty and not tested. It may have errors or typos inside, its just for info.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.object-class-which-gets-clicked').on('click', function (event) {

        $.ajax({
                url: "https://endpoint.ch/getInfo/"+id,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    appendToModal(res);
                }
        });

    });
});


function appendToModal(res){

}
```

I hope it will solve your problem and give you an idea, how to handle it. Otherwise ask back.

best regards

Comment: What I'm doing right now is an anchor on the DOM element, but using the click event seems more reasonable to use ajax. This seems like a rather simple approach, and I like it  How would you set this up server side though? A dynamic http request response that takes the last part of the request and accesses the db through that I suppose?